# How to connect and detect smartwatch in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, wear-os, wearables, samsung-galaxy-watch

I want to connect a smartwatch (e.g. Galaxy Watch) with a Flutter app on Android and receive steps or information from the smartwatch.

What should I do?

Is there no other way than using our own SDK or API, such as Samsung SDK?
Or is it possible with just a Bluetooth connection?

I looked for many ways, and what I finally found was
Using packages such as [flutter_wear_os_connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wear_os_connectivity) or [watch_connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/watch_connectivity)
The only way I could find was to connect the Wear OS app with the Android app.